Is this the right way to combine Garbage collected with none Garbage collected code in D
I have been showing interest in systems level programming languages D caught my attention, so I was told the Dlang by default the GC is on but I can turn it off however I went beyond that I wanted to combine both manual memory management with automatic memory management here is my code
// I was trying to mix Garbage collected with non Garbage collected code with D is this right //approach 
import core.stdc.stdio;
import std.stdio;
import std.array;
import core.stdc.stdlib;

void main() @trusted
{
  string word = "hello";
  int sizeOfString = word.length;
  string* words = cast(string*)malloc(char.sizeof*sizeOfString);

  string[] letters = "hello".split("");
  for(auto i = 0; i < letters.length;i++) {
    words[i] = letters[i];
  }
  writeln(*(words[4]).ptr);
  free(words);
  
}





If you malloc and free in the same scope, use scope(exit) free(words) right after checking malloc to make sure you free the memory in any case.

The code doesn't do what you think it does.
Let's walk through what's happening. (The imports are fine, so I'm omitting them for brevity.)
void main() @trusted
{
  string word = "hello";

  /* This should be size_t, not int */
  int sizeOfString = word.length;

  /* First, you don't need char.sizeof. It's always 1.
     More importantly, string isn't the same as char*. It's an array, which
     contains both a pointer and a length. If the compiler happens to put the pointer
     first, your code will work by coincidence, but as soon as you try to do
     words.length, it'll crash or return nonsense. You don't return a pointer
     to string here; you return a pointer to char.
  */
  string* words = cast(string*)malloc(char.sizeof*sizeOfString);

  /* Redundant. We can just loop through the characters (once the type of words is fixed) */
  string[] letters = "hello".split("");
  for(auto i = 0; i < letters.length;i++) {
    words[i] = letters[i];
  }

  /* More roundabout stuff that won't be necessary once we fix the earlier bits */
  writeln(*(words[4]).ptr);

  free(words);
  
}

This code does what you seem to have been trying to:
void main() {
    string word = "hello";

    /* word2 points at word.length bytes of memory. We need to track
       that length elsewhere (we can use word.length for that below.) */
    char* word2 = cast(char*)malloc(word.length);

    /* No need to split word into an array of length-1 strings anymore.
       We just copy the characters over. */
    foreach (i; 0..word.length) {
        word2[i] = word[i];
    }

    /* And this line is now just like it would be in C, as well */
    writeln(word2[4]);

    free(word2);
}


I was going to also show code that did allocate an array of length-1 strings, but that doesn't really work, since strings are dynamic arrays (dynamic arrays of immutable char, but dynamic arrays, nevertheless), and there's a lot of magic happening in the implementation that isn't defined by the specification. In particular, setting string foo; foo.length = 42 doesn't just set the field; it allocates memory, and in doing so, it assumes that foo.ptr is pointing to GC-managed memory.  We could probably get it pointing at malloced memory and get the length right by using memcpy (possibly after checking system-endianness), but it'd be a crock and probably undefined behavior, so I didn't include that in the answer.
An option for convenient handling of malloced arrays is to use slices:
void main() {
    string word = "hello";
    char* word2 = cast(char*)malloc(word.length);

    foreach (i; 0..word.length) {
        word2[i] = word[i];
    }

    /* The slice points at the same memory as word2, but
       is an actual array type.
    */
    char[] s = word2[0..word.length];
    writeln(word2[4]);// 'o'
    s[4] = 'x';
    writeln(word2[4]);// 'x'

    free(word2);
}

You should probably not attempt to resize that slice.
https://dlang.org/articles/d-array-article.html#append-on
goes into some of the gritty details of what happens when you
resize a slice, and while it normally works with copy-on-write
semantics, that seems to assume that it was already pointing
at GC-managed memory (so that it has the used bit set). I'm
not sure if it'd be well-defined to resize a slice that points
at memory you malloced up yourself.

There are some incorrect things in this answer. Array resizing indeed does allocate with the GC if needed. But it doesn't need to start out pointing at GC memory, and you aren't going to get undefined behavior from using it. memset cannot turn a GC array into a non-GC array. What you can do to get an array that points at malloc'd memory, is to slice the pointer, as you have done. Slicing a pointer does not check any kind of length, so it allows slicing any length, buyer beware. But this is exactly how you set a pointer/length combo of an array manually.

@StevenSchveighoffer Can you point to the docs that state that you can do array resizing on non-GC memory? I couldn't find anything definitive.  W.r.t. the memset bit, I think what I was referring to there was using memset to modify the (pointer, length) tuple to point it at non-GC memory, rather than turning the GC block into a non-GC block.  (That whole paragraph was a bit of guesswork based on what I could find in the documentation (D really needs a single-pdf spec to help with the language lawyer questions), hence the "a bit of a crock and probably undefined behavior" caveat.)

I don't know if there is any explicit documentation on this, but I did write the array runtime code. When you have non-GC memory, the runtime assumes it can't extend-in-place, so it will reallocate into GC memory. This does mean that the original memory will leak unless you free it a different way (for instance, stack memory will just get freed automatically). But it is not undefined behavior.
I'm unsure about the memset thing, as you have changed the answer, I don't know what it originally said. Fundamentally, strings and arrays in D are a pointer and length, nothing more.

I will say, I don't really understand the original question and what it was trying to accomplish. So whether your suggested edit is right, I have no idea.

@StevenSchveighoffer memset was just a typo that should have said memcpy, and was referring to copying the length of the non-GCed memory from wherever they're stored into the structure for a dynamic array. A way of doing foo.length = bar without triggering a realloc. Personally, I'd prefer just taking a slice of the non-GCed memory,  treating it as readonly from that slice, and doing any reallocation using realloc (taking a new slice afterwards) rather than mixing the two systems.

You should not usually treat a slice like a structure that you can set individual elements. If you want to set a slice to something explicitly, use the slicing syntax on a pointer. For instance you can set foo.length = bar without calling any magic runtime function using foo = foo.ptr[0 .. bar]. This is equivalent to just setting the internal length field. You should use the simple slice syntax foo[0 .. bar] if you aren't sure of the actual length of the original array, as this will do a bounds check.

It is as simple as marking your function(s) with the @nogc attribute. So in your code instead of @trusted you should use @nogc.

When the D compiler encounters a function that is marked as @nogc it will make sure that no memory allocations are done within the context of that function. A @nogc function is just allowed to call other @nogc functions.

You will have to replace call to split() and writeln() with something else as those are not @nogc functions.
